# How to temporarily make only 1 layer in Gimp visible (and be able to revert to previous layer visibility settings)?

Tags: gimp, layers, image-editing

I'm able to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> on the eye icon of a layer to make it the only visible layer. The problem is that after I finish editing, there is no way to return to the individual visibility setting of each layer. Everything gets visible again when I do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> including the layers that were previously not visible. The thing is I have alot of layers that are visible and alot of layers that are invisible so individually setting them to their previous visibility state is not an option. In Blender for example there is a feature where you press <kbd>/</kbd> key to temporarily make it the only visible layer so it's easier to edit it. Then after editing, just press <kbd>/</kbd> again to get back to the original visibility settings. Is there such a feature in Gimp?

Comment: No such feature as far as I know.  Perhaps you could arrange your layers better, using groups for example.

Comment: oh no.. :( well at least i know now it doesn't exist. thank you! but would be pretty powerful feature if the gimp development team included this feature.

Comment: Well, I didn't say "it doesn't exist".  Come to think of it, can't you hit Undo (Ctrl+Z) after doing your Shift+click?  Enabling and disabling layer visibility is recorded in the undo history. Obviously this will only work if you have not saved and quit the document, which will erase the undo history.

Comment: After I do the `shift`+`click`, i do my editing (since it's easier that i only see 1 layer now), and then want to return the visiblity settings to the original visibility settings I had. If i Ctrl+Z, it would just undo all my edit changes XD